# State whether the following statements are true or false and justify your answers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

(a) ∃x ∈ Z ∃y ∈ Z (x + y = 2) ∧ (x − y = 3)

(b) ∀x ∈ R ∀y ∈ R x > y −→ x^2 < y^2

(c) ∀x ∈ R ∃y ∈ R x^2 + y^2 > 1

my answers:
A.  False, let’s assume x=1 and y=1
1+1=2 (correct) for some x and y values
1-1≠2  (wrong)

B.  False, let’s assume x=2 and y=1
2>1        (correct) for all x values
2^2<1^2 (wrong)

C.  True, let’s assume x=2 and y=1
2^2+1^2>1 (correct) for all x values and y values

are they correct and well justified?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: What have you tried? Start from (a): it is quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see these statements one by one:

a) If we operate in the second condition we get $x=y+3$; which, substituting in the first one, gives us: $(3+y)+y=2$. Or what is the same $y=-1/2$, so we can not choose $y$ to be an integer.

Just as a remark, pay attention to the fact that in this case, a counterexample would not be valid as the statement doesn't talk about a property that is true for "every" integer but for a particular one ("exist $x$ and $y$ such that...").

b) Just take $x$ and $y$ bigger or equal than $1$, e.g. $x=2$ and $y=1$ would do the trick.

c) Take $x\in\mathbb{R}$. If $x>1$ or $x<-1$ then $x^2>1$, and we can take $y=0\in\mathbb{R}$. If $-1\leq x\leq 1$, in particular $x^2<2$, so $2-x^2>0$. We can then take $y=\sqrt{2-x^2}\in\mathbb{R}$ and get $y^2+x^2=2>1$.

We see that in this case, the statement is true, unlike the other ones.